Time Stopped Movement Equivalent Force Problem (Lite)
Since my question before was apparently too complicated, here is a simplified version.
Say you have a solid iron cube levitating in the air not affected by gravity and it has a $1*1*5 m$ 3-dimensional silhouette. Behind it and in front of it is an extremely thin layer of extremely dense air particles, that also has a force of 10 newtons on it, forward from the cube. What would happen?
Details:

there is normal air particles all around everything with a density of $1.2 kg$, air flow is normal
The iron cube has a density of $8kg/m^3$ and has sides of $1*1*1 m$
The layer of air is about $1.5*10^6 kg/m^3$ and has side lengths of $1*1*(3.9*10^-6) m$. The layer is being exerted on with a force of 10 newtons forward
I want to know mostly what would happen to the cube



Edit the closed question. Do not repost it.

The front of the cube freezes and cracks as the air decompresses and the temperature plummets. The near instantaneous collapse of 5m3 of pure vacuum is likely to tear chunks off the back of the cube as well. Between the explosion in front and the implosion behind it the cube is going to move some, probably small, distance backwards.
